!important doesnt work for an a href button in navbar
I have hover color change on a hrefs. I turned one of the a href to an a href button. It has its own class name, hover animation etc but because of a href has hover animation for color, button's color is changing too. Even tho I said "white!important", it still goes for a href's "orange". What should i do?
html
<li class="nav-item">
                  <a
                    class=" nav-link active bg-orange fw-normal mx-1 px-4 py-2 text-white rounded-pill"
                    aria-current="page"
                    href="#"
                    >Apply Now and Get %0 Commission<i
                      class="bi bi-arrow-down-right ms-3"
                    ></i
                  ></a>
                </li>

css
#main-menu a:hover, a:hover{color: #be4006!important;}

.bg-orange{color: #white!important;}

I wrote on top. Even tho I said "white!important", it still goes for a href's "orange". What should i do?

Are you using a combination of Bootstrap and your own stylesheets?

Hi @MarcInglis   yes

Are you importing your stylesheet before Bootstrap in your head document? Please post your CSS, it's difficult to understand why your CSS isn't working without seeing it.

I see no element with the id "main-menu"

I see that you are using !important to override the Bootstrap text-white class, but this is what is causing issues with your code. You can't apply !important to the same property more than once. Better not use text-white.
#main-menu a:hover, a:hover{color: #be4006;}
.bg-orange:hover{color: white!important;}


Further notes for anyone else coming in for an answer, this isn't actually an issue with !important. !important follows the same rules as all other CSS and cascades throughout a file. The last !important is the one that is rendered. This is actually an issue of specificity. The first selector of #main-menu a:hover, a:hover{color: #be4006;} has more specificity than .bg-orange:hover{color: white!important;} because the first selector adds an extra layer of specificity to the selector. If you were to even out the specificity from the first selector, the text would render white.

Ty for your explanation. Actually there’s more than one solution. The issue might also stem from the improper order in which Bootstrap CSS and custom CSS files are included, leading to loading sequence errors.
